# turning pointer to LinkedList of ArrayList into String

Tags: java, data-structures

I'm trying to make a linkedList (elements) of custom arrayList (coordinated )that with type Object 
the Output I am looking for is

```
Arraylist1 coord1 [2,5,1]
Arraylist2 coord2 [7,6,9]
LinkedList List1 [[2,5,1],[7,6,9]]
```

this is my output

[ 2  5  1 ]
[ 7  6  9 ]

assignment1.arrayList@33909752

assignment1.arrayList@55f96302

I tried using toString method with no luck
can someone please explain to me how to print the output with no pointers to memory.
and do I need a method to access a specific element in a certain position (in the linkList) and get its coordinates?

here is my code:
thanks

```
public class arrayList {
private Object[] myList;
private int counter = 0;
private int capacity = 100;

public arrayList() {
    myList = new Object[this.capacity];
}

public Object get(int index) {
    if (index < counter) {
        return myList[index];
    } else {
        throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }
}

public void add(Object obj) {
    myList[counter++] = obj;
}

public Object remove(int index) {
    if (index < counter) {
        Object obj = myList[index];
        int temp = index;
        myList[index] = null;

        while (temp < counter) {
            myList[temp] = myList[temp + 1];
            myList[temp + 1] = null;
            temp++;
        }

        counter--;
        return obj;
    } else {
        throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }
}

public int size() {
    return counter;
}

public void display(Object obj1) {
    System.out.print("[");
    for (int i = 0; i < this.size(); i++) {
        System.out.print(" " + this.get(i) + " ");
    }
    System.out.print("]");
    System.out.println();

}
```

}

```
public class linkedList {

public Cube firstLink;
public Cube next;

linkedList() {
    firstLink = null;
}

public void insertFirstLink(Object e) {

    Cube newLink = new Cube(e);

    newLink.next = firstLink;
    firstLink = newLink;
}

public boolean isEmpty() {
    return (firstLink == null);
}

public Cube removeFirst() {

    Cube linkReference = firstLink;

    if (!isEmpty()) {
        firstLink = firstLink.next;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Empty Linked list!");

    }
    return linkReference;

}

public void display() {

    Cube theLink = firstLink;

    while (theLink != null) {
        theLink.display();
        theLink = theLink.next;
        System.out.println();
    }
}

public Cube find(Object obj) {
    Cube theLink = firstLink;
    if (!isEmpty()) {
        while (theLink.obj != obj) {
            if (theLink.next == null) {
                return null;
            } else {
                theLink = theLink.next;
            }
        }

    } else {
        System.out.println("Empty List!");
    }

    return theLink;
}

public Cube removeLink(Object obj) {
    Cube currentLink = firstLink;
    Cube previousLink = firstLink;

    while (currentLink.obj != obj) {
        if (currentLink.next == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            previousLink = currentLink;
            currentLink = currentLink.next;
        }
    }

    if (currentLink == firstLink) {
        firstLink = firstLink.next;
    } else {

        previousLink.next = currentLink.next;
    }
    return currentLink;

}
```

}

```
public class Cube {
public Object obj;
public Cube next;

public Cube(Object obj) {
    this.obj = obj;

}

public void display() {
    obj.toString();
    System.out.println(obj);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    arrayList coord1 = new arrayList();
    coord1.add(new Integer(2));
    coord1.add(new Integer(5));
    coord1.add(new Integer(1));

    arrayList coord2 = new arrayList();
    coord2.add(new Integer(7));
    coord2.add(new Integer(6));
    coord2.add(new Integer(9));


    coord1.display(coord1);
    coord2.display(coord2);


    linkedList position1 = new linkedList();
    position1.insertFirstLink(coord1);
    position1.insertFirstLink(coord2);

    position1.display();


}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You may consider looking into [generics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java), [code style](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html), and [collections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_collections_framework).

Answer (score 0):

According to the API, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println(java.lang.Object)

You put a Object into `System.out.println(x)` will eventually call [`String.valueOf(x)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(java.lang.Object)) which utlimitly call `x.toString()`. Put this #1

In `linkedList.display()` it will call `Cube.display()`. `Cube.display()` will prints its encapsulated object. The object turns out to be an `arrayList`. From #1, the method call would become `arrayList.toString()`. However, `arrayList` did not implement `toString()`. Don't worry, Java got your back. Since all non-primitive type extends Object, arrayList will has is [`toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) method inherited from Object. This is the Object implementation, to print the object id. If you don't like it, you can define your own toString() in `arrayList` scope.

**Update 1**

You may wonder why the first `arraylist` could print something meaningful out. It is because you call its `arraylist.display()` directly, not `System.out.println(coord1)`

**Update 2**

There are some anti pattern in your code.

1. Class name should be in [camel case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case)
   , like Cube so as ArrayList, LinkedList.
2. Why `arrayList.display()` need a argument which also reference to itself but you never use it (i.e. `obj1` is totally ignored)?
   `coord1.display()` is good enough, you don't need `coord1.display(coord1)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to do following changes:

In your arrayList class you need to change methods display(Object obj1) and override toString() method:

```
public void display(Object obj1) {
    System.out.println(obj1);
}

@Override
public String toString() {

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("[");
    for (int i = 0; i < counter - 1; i++) {
        sb.append(myList[i] + ",");
    }

    sb.append(myList[counter - 1] + "]");
    return sb.toString();
}
```

In class linkedList change display and override toString() as below:

```
public void display() {
    System.out.println(this.toString());
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Cube temp = firstLink;
    sb.append("[");
    while (temp != null) {
        sb.append(temp.obj.toString());
        temp = temp.next;
        if (temp != null)
            sb.append(",");
    }
    sb.append("]");

    return sb.toString();
}
```

}

Note: It will be printing linked list in reverse order, because your implementation of LinkedList is storing data in reverse order.